# How to join 2 temp tables?

Tags: sql, join, temp-tables

I have created 2 temp tables and I'm having problems joining them.

table #1

```
Create Table #First_Pay(
SAID int,
First_Payment date)
select b.CUSTNMBR, min(b.docdate) as first_payment
from RM20101 b
where b.CUSTNMBR = '1973204005'
and b.CHEKNMBR > '1'
Group by b.CUSTNMBR
```

table #2

```
Create Table #First_Bil(
SAID int,
First_Bill date)
Select a.CUSTNMBR, MIN(a.Tax_Date) as First_Bill
from SOP30200 as a
where a.CUSTNMBR = '1973204005'
Group by a.CUSTNMBR
```

and I used this query:

```
Select a.SAID, a.First_Bill, b.First_Payment
From #First_Bil a 
Full Join
#First_Pay b
On a.SAID = b.SAID;


drop table #First_Bil
drop table #First_Pay
```

but I'm getting blanks. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you inserting values in the temp tables?

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to `INSERT` any data to the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just selecting data after creating a temp table you have to insert it into the temp table:

```
Create Table #First_Pay(SAID int,
                        First_Payment date)

insert into #First_Pay select b.CUSTNMBR, min(b.docdate) as first_payment
                       from RM20101 b
                       where b.CUSTNMBR = '1973204005'
                       and b.CHEKNMBR > '1'
                       Group by b.CUSTNMBR

Create Table #First_Bil(SAID int,
                        First_Bill date)

insert into #First_Bil Select a.CUSTNMBR, MIN(a.Tax_Date) as First_Bill
                       from SOP30200 as a
                       where a.CUSTNMBR = '1973204005'
                       Group by a.CUSTNMBR
```

Comment: You are awesome sir, it's things like this just makes me feel like an idiot

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have data in your tables? you don't insert anywhere after you create them? Make sure to have an insert row